# multiple models from one controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

- i have three modeles, Question table, Answeroption table, 
  Correctanswer table.The QuestionId of Questiontable is foreign key in the Answeroption tbl and the AnswerId Of Answer tbl is Foreign key in the correctanswer tbl. I made three storedprocedures,i did all the work
  in one storedprocedure, such that when i exec sp.insertintoquestion,
  it insert data in the questiontable, it the same time it insert the
  foreign keys in the respective tables. Now i dont know how to insert
  data to different models from controller and how to show it in a
  view. I am new, Please help me.

---

My stored procedures are the following.
  This stored procedure insert data into the AnswerOptiontbl and insert foreign key into the Correctanswer tbl.

```
  ALTER procedure [dbo].[InsertIntoAnswer]
(
    @questionid int,
    @OptionA nvarchar(50),
    @OptionB nvarchar(50),
    @OptionC nvarchar(50),
    @OptionD nvarchar(50),
    @CorrectOption nvarchar(50)

)
as
begin
 insert into Answertbl(QuestionId,OptionA,OptionB,OptionC,OptionD,CorrectOption)
    values(@questionid,@OptionA,@OptionB,@OptionC,@OptionD,@CorrectOption)
    end
```

sp.insertcorrectanswer. This stored procedure insert data into the CorrectAnswer table.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[InsertCorrectAnswer]
(
    @AnswerId int,
    @CorrectAnswer nvarchar(50)
)
as
begin
        insert into CorrectAnswertbl(AnswerId,CorrectAnswer)
        values(@AnswerId,@CorrectAnswer)
        end
```

Now i define my whole logic in the following storedprocedure. sp.insertintoquestion. As this sp exec it will insert data into questiontbl, answeroption table and correctanswer tbl. and the same time insert FK questionid to Answeroption table and Fk AnswerId to CorrectAnswer tbl

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[InsertIntoQuestion]
        (
            @QuestionText nvarchar(50),
            @QuestionTypeId int,
            @QuestionLevelId int,
            @questionid int out,
            @OptionA nvarchar(50),
            @OptionB nvarchar(50),
            @OptionC nvarchar(50),
            @OptionD nvarchar(50),
            @CorrectOption nvarchar(50),
            @AnswerId int out,
            @CorrectAnswer nvarchar(50)

        )
        as 
        begin
           insert into Questiontbl(QuestionText,QuestionTypeId,QuestionLevelId)
           values( @QuestionText,@QuestionTypeId,@QuestionLevelId)

           select @questionid= scope_identity();
           exec InsertIntoAnswer @questionid,@OptionA,@OptionB,@OptionC,@OptionD,@CorrectOption

           select @AnswerId=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
           exec InsertCorrectAnswer @AnswerId,@CorrectAnswer
           end
```

As i am using DataBase Ist approach so in the Repositry class i define the following method, and pass parameters required parameters to storedprocedures. But i am not sure about my method wheather it is correct or not.

```
public void InsertQuestions( string QuestionText,int QuestionTypeId, int QuestionLevelId, string OptionA, string OptionB,string OptionC,string OptionD,string CorrectOption,string CorrectAnswer,ObjectParameter questionid=null,ObjectParameter AnswerId=null)

        {
            db.InsertIntoQuestion(QuestionText, QuestionTypeId, QuestionLevelId, questionid, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD, CorrectOption, AnswerId, CorrectAnswer);
        }
```

i write the following code in controller. The QuestionTypeId and QuestionLevelId are the foreign keys in the questiontbl from QuestionTypetbl and QuestionLeveltbl. i write these in selectlist. During insertion i will select these two in dropdownlist from there respective tables.

```
public class MyScoreController : Controller
    {
        ScoreApplication app = new ScoreApplication();
        scoredbEntities db = new scoredbEntities();
        //
        // GET: /MyScore/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.QuestionTypeId = new SelectList(db.QuestionTypetbls, "QuestionTypeId", "QuestionType");
            ViewBag.QuestionLevelId = new SelectList(db.QuestionLeveltbls, "QuestionLevelId", "QuestionLevel");
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               //Now i dont now what to do here.
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The following is the view, but this view is only of one model, and i dont know how to show data of other models in the same view.

```
 @model MyScoreProject.Models.Questiontbl

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Questiontbl</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionText, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuestionText)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuestionText)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionTypeId, "QuestionTypeId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("QuestionTypeId", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuestionTypeId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionLevelId, "QuestionLevelId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("QuestionLevelId", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuestionLevelId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have a different view-model and domain-model. I assume you have a layered architecture. The models you mentioned supposed to be in a different layer. There you have your models corresponding to your tables.

In the MVC project, you should have view-models in the Models folder. These models are based on the data you need to show on view. These models are composed of different properties(or computed properties) from domain-models. Thus you can pass this view-model into view and get data related to different domain-models(or BusinessObjects.

**EXAMPLE**

```
public class MyViewModel{
    //some properties from questions to display
    //.
    //.
    //.
    //some properties from answer to capture
    //.
    //.
    //.
}
```

**And in view use:**

```
@model MyScoreProject.Models.MyViewModel
```

**EDIT:1(Controller)**

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Question q = bal.GetQuestion(someQuestionParameter);
        Answer a = bal.GetAnswer(someAnswerParameter)

        MyViewModel m = new MyViewModel(q,a);
        return View(m);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           //from data of model, construct questions and answer objects and save them in DB
        }
        return View(m);
    }
```

Comment: ya but what i have to to in the controller. i need logic that how can i use the method i define in repositry class in the action method of controller.

Comment: Edited my answer...hope it helps